# Why an 'Uncaught ReferenceError: idName is not defined' is working in Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have what appears to be a working event listener attached to a button click event. Example is below. But, my console is throwing an error **`Uncaught ReferenceError: followBtn is not defined`**.

It's driving me crazy as I'm unsure how to fix it.

```js
followBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var followText = followBtn;

    //set state of current button text
    if (followText.textContent === 'Follow') {
        //if above is ttrue, change it to the following
        followText.textContent = 'Following';
        followText.classList.add('followed');
    } else {
        //otherwise, keep the text as the following
        followText.textContent = 'Follow';
        followText.classList.remove('followed');
    }
});
```

```css
.follow {
    margin: 0.2em 0.5em;
}

button.follow, button.followed {
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

button.follow {
    background: transparent;
    color: magenta;
}

button.followed {
    background: magenta;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<button class="follow" id="followBtn">Follow</button>
```

Below is a screenshot of the error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: where is it mentioning "idName"?

Comment: Where are you initializing `idName` field?

Comment: @ewong - It was generic for the naming of the question. I've edited it.

Comment: You need something like `document.querySelector("#idName").addEventListener(...)`.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried this in codepen using chrome and it seems fine. I'm not sure where the error is

Comment: @Phil - Chrome. And it's updated.

Comment: @MarkTaylor - I've updated the OP. Like I said in the OP, it works, but it's still throwing an error in the console. I've included a screenshot above.

Comment: We need to access the DOM element then add event listener. `document.getElementById("idName").addEventListener("click", function(){})`

Comment: @upender - If I do that, then I get another error that says `Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: Your console is using strict linting and as such, is showing a syntax error. The reason your code actually works is explained in the linked duplicate. As advised, it's best not to rely on this feature

Comment: Copy that @Phil. Thanks.

Comment: @Phil - The answer on that question basically says I need to use `document.getElementById('idName').addEventListener(function() {});`, but doing that throws a `TypeError` on the `addEventListener`.

Comment: Try moving `document.getElementById('').addEventListener(...)` inside the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler or move your script to the bottom of the page. Also, ensure that you have used right `id` to find element.

Comment: Is your button `id` actually `idName` or is it `followBtn`? I would first add `const followBtn = document.getElementById('followBtn');`, then the rest of the code in your screenshot should work